# Triangle inequality how is it applied here

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In my book they say the following : $f$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and $\sup \mid f \mid = J \in \mathbb{R}^+$ :

> If we have : $\mid f(x+h) - f(x) - hf'(x) \mid \leq \frac{Kh^2}{2}$ for some $K > 0$ then by the triangle inequality we have : 
>   $$\mid hf'(x) \mid \leq 2J + \frac{Kh^2}{2}$$

I know the triangle inequality yet I don't see how it's applied here. I mean we have $\mid f(x+h) - f(x) - hf'(x) \mid \leq 2J + \mid hf'(x) \mid$, but then how do you correlate both inequalities to get the one in the yellow box ?

Thank you !

Comment: $|f(x+h) - f(x) - hf'(x)| \le |f(x+h)| +|f(x)| + |hf'(x)| \le J + J + |hf'(x)|$.

Comment: @fleablood what you are saying doesn't help at all, but it's ok see Mindlack's answer

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read to closely.  But it's often called the reverse triangle inequality when you do $|a|-|b| \le |a-b|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|hf’(x)| \leq |hf’(x)+f(x)-f(x+h)| + |f(x+h)| +|-f(x)| \leq \frac{Kh^2}{2}+2J$$

Comment: Oh ok that's a nasty trick... Thank you !